# Windows 10 BSOD on Asus zenbook

Tags: bsod, windows-10

Please help me finding the reason of BSODs. Thx
Download minidumps on:
www.uschovna.cz/en/zasilka/FRHUX4YFYJ647E64-FUY

**UPDATE**

memtest runs every configuration well except of the configuration SMP parallel: it runs for 2 minutes normally (all four  / | \ circulates equally), then the 4th core slows down and finally it freezes in the state captured on the picture in attachment. When frozen, no value changes, no response on any key pressed, only plus sign in "Memtest86+" still flashes O:) 
BTW Some people complains that Test #7 freezes as a false positive on ver 5.01 when in SMP mode.

memtest freezes picture: www.uschovna.cz/en/zasilka/FRZFBWF3U7AR9STA-F8Z

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: I have just downloaded his dump files and readed one of them with Windbg.For now i've seen something about *IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL* .I wiil have a detailed look

Comment: Ok, the first dump file is related to *IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL* , and is process is *msmpeng.exe* (Windows Defender). The second dump file is related to *MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)* ,and it's process is *devenv.exe* (Visual Studio)

Comment: make sure the HDD is fine. run **chkdsk /f** to detect file system issues.

Comment: Chkdsk run once, found no problem, may be some better disk diagnostic program can find more

Comment: The download link is broken