# Subtype 0x6000 of bugcheck 0x1A (MEMORY_MANAGEMENT)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

Where to find what does subtype 0x6000 of bugcheck 0x1A (MEMORY_MANAGEMENT) means?

It is not listed there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557391.aspx

Comment: this is not documented. We have no idea what it means. Ask this the Microsoft support if you got such a Bugcheck.

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's one from the bugchecks here: http://superuser.com/questions/957021/windows-10-bsod-on-asus-zenbook (It seems that you already analyzed them.)

Comment: ok, I haven't looked at the parameter, just at the callstack. Here some IO operations where done.